# Using the .Clients in Alchemy

Tags: a4t

I'm using the Alchemy NuGet package `Alchemy4Tridion.Plugin` (v1.0.9) and also the HellowWorld NuGet package `Alchemy4Tridion.Sample.HelloWorld` (v 1.0.0.0 beta 6) to create a new Alchemy Plugin.

In the `HelloService` Controller we have a simple method to call the CoreService with the built-in Alchemy Core Service proxy.  However, the Visual Studio Intellisense gives me a warning on the line `return Client.GetApiVersion();`

> 'Deprecated, use .Clients instead'

Any examples of using the `.Clients` approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this .Clients property has been included to give you a wrapper around the different core service implementations. Alchemy should automatically make a call to the correct core service for the Tridion / SDL Web version (so you don't need to write two versions of the plugins, each using it's own core service call, or do any other tricks in your code).

Instead off calling `Client.GetApiVersion()`, you should be able to call `Clients.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.GetApiVersion()`.

Comment: Harald is correct! You can find the latest documentation around using Clients here: https://www.alchemywebstore.com/help/for-developers/category/plugin-anatomy/web-services#using-tridion-core-services

Comment: There's also a new Clients.GetContentManagerVersion() method which returns an enum, so that might be a preferable alternative in this particular case.